# Getting nullPointer in image recognition attempt

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, graphics, image-recognition

I am getting a nullPointerError on the CascadeClassifier in triDetect. I need to write a code to find the number of circles, triangles, rectangles, and lines. Please do not roast this code it is terrible but I really need help. If you have any suggestions or help please give whatever advice you can. I need this done in the next two days (today is june 15 2019) so if it is past that you don't need to spend time on this. Please offer any help in making this better and solving my issue. Thank you.

I have tried changing the cascadeclassifier to other things but i believe this is the best way. Please help.

```
public class main extends JComponent implements MouseInputListener {
    static int rects = 0;
    static int triangles = 0;
    static int circles = 0;
    static int lines = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, IOException {
        System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );

        Robot robot = new Robot();
        Rectangle screenSize = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(screenSize);    


            JFrame window = new JFrame("Image Recognition");
            main run = new main();
            window.add(run, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            window.pack();
            window.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            window.setVisible(true);
            window.setSize(300,500); //300,500

            window.addMouseListener(run);

            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
            JLabel lbl=new JLabel();
            lbl.setIcon(icon);
            window.add(lbl);

            window.repaint();


            File outputFile = new File("image.jpg");
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", outputFile);
            File input = new File("C:\\Users\\ericl\\eclipse-workspace\\ImageRecognition\\image.jpg");
            BufferedImage buffImage = ImageIO.read(input);
            BufferedImage imageCopy =
                    new BufferedImage(buffImage.getWidth(), buffImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
            imageCopy.getGraphics().drawImage(buffImage, 0, 0, null);

            byte[] data = ((DataBufferByte) imageCopy.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();  


            Mat mat = new Mat(image.getHeight(),image.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
            mat.put(0, 0, data);           
            Imgcodecs.imwrite("C:\\Users\\ericl\\eclipse-workspace\\ImageRecognition\\input.jpg", mat);



            new main().detectTris(mat);

            window.repaint();

        }

    public void detectTris(Mat mat) {
        System.out.println("\nRunning detection");

        CascadeClassifier shapeDetector = new CascadeClassifier(getClass().getResource("C:\\Users\\ericl\\eclipse-workspace\\OpenCVImageRecognition\\shapes\\triEx.jpg").getPath());

        MatOfRect triDetections = new MatOfRect();
        shapeDetector.detectMultiScale(mat, triDetections);

        System.out.println(String.format("Detected %s triangles", triDetections.toArray().length));
    }


    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        String strRect = String.valueOf(rects);
        String strTri = String.valueOf(triangles);
        String strCirc = String.valueOf(circles);
        String strLine = String.valueOf(lines);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(90,10,200,400);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans", Font.PLAIN, 80));
        g.drawString(strRect, 100, 100);
        g.drawString(strTri, 100, 200);
        g.drawString(strCirc, 100, 300);
        g.drawString(strLine, 100, 400);
        g.fillRect(200, 40, 60, 60);
        int y[] = {200,150,200}; 
        int x[] = {200,230,260};
        g.fillPolygon(x,y, 3);
        g.fillOval(200, 240, 55, 55);
        g.fillRect(220, 340, 5, 60);
    }
}
```

Expecting output to be a window with the amount of each shape from the screenshot in red.

Comment: sorry Ive never posted on here before but i need help cause this is due monday morning so i was looking for anything i could get as quickly as possible @StephenC

Comment: Read: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: If I were you, I would edit my question to remove all references to urgency.  Your urgency is not relevant to us ...

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an NPE because you are using `getResource` incorrectly.

```
    getClass().getResource(
        "C:\\Users\\ericl\\eclipse-workspace\\OpenCVImageRecognition\\shapes\\triEx.jpg")
        .getPath()
```

The `getGetResource` method requires a resource path.  You have given it a full (absolute) file system path.   The `getGetResource` is then attempting to look that up in the resource namespace and failing.

Solution:

1. Read up on how resource search actually works.   For example: 
   [Location-Independent Access to Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html)
2. Read the [javadoc](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/javadoc/org/opencv/objdetect/CascadeClassifier.html) for `CascadeClassifier`
3. Decide if you *should* be using resources in this context.
4. If you decide to continue trying to use resources:

   1. Ensure that the resource you are trying to load actually is a JAR file (or directory tree) that is on the application's runtime classpath.
   2. Correct the resource path you are using.
   3. Work out how to deal with the case where the resource is not a file in the file system ... which is what `CascadeClassifier` requires.
5. If you decide to use a regular file, change your code to something like the following:

---

```
CascadeClassifier shapeDetector = new CascadeClassifier(
    "C:\\Users\\ericl\\eclipse-workspace\\OpenCVImageRecognition\\shapes\\triEx.jpg");
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion. I read up on CascadeClassifier and used your suggestion but now am getting this error:  CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static\opencv\modules\core\src\persistence.cpp:719: error: (-49:Unknown error code -49) Input file is empty in function 'cv::FileStorage::Impl::open'
].  Is this saying the file does not exist? I have the correct file address.

Comment: No.  It is saying that the file is empty.   Here is the (C++) code that produces the message: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp

Comment: And that means what exactly? It is an existing file with an image of a triangle.

Comment: That's not what it thinks.  Read the code link.  Generally speaking, it will be you that is wrong ... not the library.  (Hint: the file could be mangled ... or have the wrong file suffix ... or something like that.)